# What happens after SSL/TLS certificate expires?

Tags: tls, network, certificates

This is what I understand about SSL/TLS protocol:

1. Web server sends public key with cert.
2. Client checks cert validity locally using trusted CA list.
3. Client encrypts symmetric key using server's public key.
4. SSL/TLS session created.

Now my question is, what happens if client wants to re-check cert revocation with CA on step 2 (maybe cert was expired)? In this case, I assume client would need to "fetch" to CA to get maybe new CRL? If so, how do we ensure that "fetch" communication between client and CA is secure? Also, how do browsers manage certs? Do certs get updated automatically when browser updates? How about local (trusted roots) CAs? Plus, if browsers only trusts (pre-installed certs) certain CAs, why would anyone want to include (or trust) additional cert from another CA?

Comment: *"Client encrypts symmetric key using server's public key."* - wrong, at least today. This is a (very simplified) description of RSA key exchange, which is considered obsolete and isn't even available anymore with TLS 1.3

Comment: Please focus to a single question and do not merge everything into one question. Also, certificate expiration can be checked without checking revocation and if certificate is expired no revocation need to be checked - the certificate is considered invalid anyway. Also parts of your question look like they ask about the server certificate and others ask about the root certificate and for some parts it is not clear what kind of certificate you actually mean (server or root).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Expiration

**Expiration** is handled inside the certificate. Each certificate contains two fields, "Not Before" and "Not After", which determine when a certificate is considered valid. That means as soon as the client receives the certificate from the server, the client can determine that for the current time settings, this is not considered valid.

## Revokation

**Revokation** is handled in multiple ways, and at the descretion. This blog post, aptly titled "[Revokation is broken](https://scotthelme.co.uk/revocation-is-broken/)", explains why both methods suck.

But since we want to make this answer self-contained, let's look at both methods, CRLs and OCSP.

### Certificate Revokation Lists

When a CA signs a certificate, it determines that it wants to use CRLs. The certificate then contains an URL, usually provided by the CA itself, which contains a list of certificates provided by the CA, which are considered revoked for one reason or another.

This is a horrible practice, because these lists are long and if the endpoint is slow to respond, your connection to the site will take a while, because the client has to check whether or not the certificate is valid.

### Online Certificate Status Protocol

Similar to CRLs, the OCSP method lists and endpoint in the certificate, where the client can ask "Is this certificate valid right now?", and the server answers yes or no.

This has the unfortunate downside of leaking to the CA which sites you try to access. While this may not be troublesome for `https://security.stackexchange.com`, it may be for `https://hivclinic.ca`, `https://yourdivorcelawyer.com` or similar sites. That and you still have the performance problem of before.

### OCSP Stapling

The idea is quite simple. The server itself asks the OCSP endpoint periodically whether its own certificate is still valid, and then staples a signed response to the certificate. Akin to "Oh and by the way, my CA told me my cert is valid until at least 22:21. Here's their signature."

Sounds great, right? Well, the stapling implementation in nginx is broken right now, and it just...doesn't staple, even if you tell it to. But in theory, this is pretty solid.

## How do browsers manage certificates?

That depends on the browsers. Chromium-based browsers depend on your operating system's certificate storage, while Firefox maintains its own certificate storage.

Each of those have update mechanisms, although root certificates aren't updated all that often.